# Changing symbology/color in kml when exported from ArcGIS/QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, kml, symbology, export

I have marked some points and used symbology in ArcGIS/QGIS but when I export the file to kml, the color/symbology changes and only single color/symbol remains.

Is there any possible way that the symbol/color that I use in ArcGIS or QGIS may retain in kml as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added symbology via ArcGIS and it was done. NO Idea what was the issue.
Methodology:

1. go to layer properties->symbology->categories->give symbols and colors.
2. using conversion tool, convert "layer to kml"

I used ArcGIS 9.3 for this.